# how to change default effect of jquery toggle..?

Tags: jquery

I am just trying to learn jQuery and I found one problem. I have a toggle effect by which I can hide and show my div. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#butShowHideSlow").click(function () {
            $("#divShowHideSlow").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="butShowHideSlow">Click Me</button>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 47px; border: solid 1px black; background-color: white; text-align: center;" id="divShowHideSlow">Div that hide and show slowly</div>
```

Initially my `div` is there but I want to hide my div initially. I think it's easy but I am new to jQuery so can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first toggle to `hide()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divShowHideSlow").hide();
  $("#butShowHideSlow").click(function () {
   $("#divShowHideSlow").toggle("slow");
  });
 });
</script>
<button id="butShowHideSlow">Click Me</button>
<div style="width:300px;height:47px; border: solid 1px black;background-color:white;text-align:center;" id="divShowHideSlow">Div that hide and show slowly</div>
```

Comment: You should put the `.hide()` inside `$(document).ready`, or it won't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to the top of your script:

```
$("#divShowHideSlow").hide();
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6TLaw/

Answer (score 1):

`$("#divShowHideSlow").hide();`

Or add `display:none` to the div style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#butShowHideSlow").click(function () {
    $("#divShowHideSlow").toggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<button id="butShowHideSlow">Click Me</button>
<div style="display: none; width:300px;height:47px; border: solid 1px black;background-color:white;text-align:center;" id="divShowHideSlow">Div that hide and show slowly</div>
```

Comment: Some indication of what you've changed and **why** they should do it would help to improve your answer.

Comment: He added `display:none` to the inline css, which is ugly as sin but works.

Comment: I have removed this `$("#divShowHideSlow").toggle("slow");` from second line and I have made changes in to `<div style="display: none; ....` so on, so It would hide first `div` element and when he click on it it will start `toggle`, this isn't the best answer but it still works thanks for asking